# Car hits on speedbreaker from beneath

Tags: suspension, car

Suzuki Khyber 1990. Car bumps on speedbreaker giving a terrifying sound of hitting and leading to damaging parts. I did use suspensions but when 4 people sit in that it does the same. Don't know what to do? Really worried

Comment: 4 people of 50kgs each or 4 people of 110kgs each?

Comment: 50 to 70 kg approx

Comment: Are you going slow over the speed bumps?

Comment: Yes alot slower. I eve tried do a cross the bump diagonally. But still no chance

Comment: Find a different route? " I did use suspensions " ? whats that mean?

Comment: There's a single route  to my home so have to go through this everytime i take the car out

Comment: Suspension: is the system of tires, tire air, springs, shock absorbers and linkages that connects a vehicle to its wheels and allows relative motion between the two.[ Suspension systems must support both roadholding/handling and ride quality, which are at odds with each other. The tuning of suspensions involves finding the right compromise. It is important for the suspension to keep the road wheel in contact with the road surface as much as possible, because all the road or ground forces acting on the vehicle do so through the contact patches of the tires.

Comment: @Chaudhry What he was asking is what you meant by *using* suspensions. Did you try different suspension options or what?

Comment: Yup. I did use different suspensions but they didn't do well.